# Libreoffice jars not found running spring-boot from command-line

Tags: spring-boot, command-line

I'm trying to run a spring-boot application from command line that uses jodreports but it fails with some FileNotFoundExceptions related to Libreoffice dependencies. The files exists but what I find strange is that it seems to be looking up wrong paths.

```
Failed to scan [file:/<mypath>/.m2/repository/org/libreoffice/juh/5.2.0/jurt.jar]
```

Notice that the path includes the folder /juh but the file is jurt.jar. Moreover, the file should be jurt-5.2.0.jar but the version number is not used in the filename. The missed files are also in the folders /juh, /jurt, /ridl, etc.

I'm launchig with the following command line (tried other combinations and none worked):

```
mvn spring-boot:start -P dev -s <path>\settings.xml -f .\application -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

From my STS IDE the application boots without problem but I can't figure out how it does to accomplish ok.

I also have noticed that that the IDE console shows this first line:

```
[CPRO][DEBUG] [2019-05-29 13:50:03] [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(52)] Application started with classpath: [file:/D:/CTyPD/proyectos/repo/calcprod/application/target/classes/, file:/D:/CTyPD/proyectos/repo/calcprod/service-impl/target/classes/, file:/D:/CTyPD/proyectos/repo/calcprod/integration/target/classes/, file:/D:/CTyPD/proyectos/repo/calcprod/service-api/target/classes/, file:/D:/CTyPD/proyectos/repo/calcprod/repository/target/classes/, file:/D:/CTyPD/proyectos/repo/calcprod/model/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/rafael.cano/.m2/repository/org/libreoffice/juh/, file:/C:/Users/rafael.cano/.m2/repository/org/libreoffice/jurt/]
```

which at the end  includes two libreoffice paths, but I can't find where they come from, and why the lines add these and not other dependencies.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
I didn't notice that the Libreofice messages were warnings. I've come up with a different command line and I'm getting different error messages. I will delete this post and ask in another one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you don't required to mention settings.xml file path, that one will take care by maven.
You can run spring boot application in 2 ways.

1. Command line :

   - Go to application root folder and execute below command

     > `mvn clean install -Pdev`
   - then go to target folder and execute below command

     > `java -jar app-name-*.(jar/war)`
2. Spring Boot Maven Plugin:

   > `mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev`  OR
   >   `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

[Spring Boot reference document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html)

Comment: Thanks Seshu, I've tried but those gives me errors and my target folder contains a war file. I've got to something positioning in the /application folder (my application is a multi module project generated with Spring Roo) and running another command, but I get new errors and I have noticed that the Libreoffice jar mesages are warnings. I'll close this question because it is following a different way.